# Multiple filter regex

Tags: regex, datatables

Sample Data:

`ID Name User
12 Test Same
14 Xyz  Joe
15 Abc  John
16 Def  Bill
17 Ghi  Donald`

If a user searches for Abc or Joe, he should get that rows.

Regex:

`'Abc|Joe'`

Output:

```
14 Xyz Joe
15 Abc John
```

Now, if the user further searches for e, it should filter based on the previous output(2 rows retrieved), so I will just get 14 Xyz Joe . Is this possible using regex?

I am trying to have all this in one regex.

```
`'Abc|Joe and the second filter goes here (All in one regex)'`
```

Use case: The user selects checkboxes to set the filters he wants to apply on the data (All the data in the columns Name and User are available). He may then search again on the filtered result using a search textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((firstRegex)(?:.*(secondRegex)))|((secondRegex)(?:.*(firstRegex)))

((Abc|Xyz)(?:.*(Jo)))|((Jo)(?:.*(Abc|Xyz)))
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD3zV2/1)

we don't know which regex would before or after,so it have two case and we use `|` combine these case.If have more search,suggest you write some code.

Answer (score 1):

For the 2 filters:

```regex
/^\d+\s+(?:Abc|Xyz|Def)\s+\S*(?:Jo|ill).*/mg;
```

If the user doesn't specify the second filter, you could just leave it empty as `(?:)`.

---

I'm positive you could create these kind of expressions if you read a couple of minutes about regex syntax, so allow me to recommend:

1. [Regular Expressions Tutorial (regular-expressions.info)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). A quite comprehensive tutorial to learn regex.
2. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). Allows you to test different expressions and understand the way a pattern matches the subjet string.

Comment: I noticed you added extra spaces and I changed the regex. It should match as requested. [Test online](https://regex101.com/r/tB7wV0/1)